# Check the status of OrientDB - broken vertices

Tags: database, status, orientdb

I'm using OrientDB for a somewhat large amount of data - since importing takes some weeks.
Now, when I'm almost done I get

> Database could contain broken vertices

Can I test the database for problems? Or does it just 'act' as if all is right?
I've had a previous iteration where I found out, later, not all vertices and edges were imported correctly.
One of the reasons why I presume something is out of the ordinary is the error message

> ..ODatabaseException: RecordId cannot support negative cluster id

Current approach is try to print each vertex (type), since a broken vertex appears to throw errors when trying to read all the properties - NOT on fetch-only. Seems suboptimal for over 100M vertices. And how for the Edges?

Answer (score 0):

"Database could contain broken vertices" appears on `drop class` command to warn you about dropping classes instead of using `delete vertex`. Follow the suggestions if you don't want broken edges.

About the negative RID you could also use `repair database` console command.

How you did insert the graph? With or without tx? Did you even stop the process while it was running? Are you importing against plocal or remote protocol?

Comment: Do you suggest to delete all the vertices of class X one-by-one or the dropVertexType? I inserted with tx, using the Java API. I did have some memory issues (i.e. crash) while inserting vertices and edges. Also ran multiple inserts at the same time (because of the amount of vertices/edges). I use the remote:localhost/x argument for the OrientGraphFactory, but why is remote/plocal a thingy?

Comment: Btw, the 'repair database' command what do you reckon it would take? Waiting for 1,5 hour now, with no progress indication... DB now consists of 259M edges and 85M vertices